# date returned from dateFromString method

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, nsdate, ios6.1

Please help me solve the problem.

(The values for objValidation.aRange.MinimumValue, objValidation.aRange.MaximumValue come from web services)

(I am getting wrong dates in firstDate, secondDate.)

```
NSDateFormatter *df  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
                [df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
                NSDate *myDate = [df dateFromString:inputString];
                [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
                NSLog(@"objValidation.aRange.MinimumValue : %@,objValidation.aRange.MaximumValue :%@, inputString : %@",objValidation.aRange.MinimumValue,objValidation.aRange.MaximumValue,inputString);
                NSDate *firstDate = [df dateFromString:objValidation.aRange.MinimumValue];
                NSDate *secondDate = [df dateFromString:objValidation.aRange.MaximumValue];
                NSLog(@"myDate : %@,firstDate :%@, secondDate : %@",myDate,firstDate,secondDate);
                [df release];
```

Output:

```
objValidation.aRange.MinimumValue : 8/20/2013
objValidation.aRange.MaximumValue :12/31/9999
inputString : 08/22/2013 
myDate : 2013-08-21 18:30:00 +0000
firstDate :2013-08-19 18:30:00 +0000
secondDate : 1999-12-30 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: Do keep in mind that NSLog dumps NSDate values in UTC, not Indian time.

Comment: Looks alright to me, considering the timezone offset of NSLog that has been posted about a 100 times.

Comment: @MarcusAdams I tried removing that line, but no help. It works find in iOS 5/5.1 but not in iOS 6/6.1

Comment: Do you think is their any problem with the formatters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date retuned is correct, but you do not take in account the timezone.

All `NSDate` object do not have an timezone. So when you parse the date the system timezone will be used.

Comment: But the same works fine in iOS 5/5.1 simulators. It fails in iOS 6/6.1.

Comment: @HotLicks I am not sure, why it works in iOS 5. Is their any issue with dateFromString method? Please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Mahesh - I suspect you're simply misinterpreting the results.  Once again, when you use NSLog to dump an NSDate object, it is dumped in UTC, not local time.  In India this means that midnight dates will appear to be 1 day earlier than what you expect.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, I understand that. But why does the secondDate (1999-12-30 18:30:00 +0000) for input to dateFromString method (objValidation.aRange.MaximumValue :12/31/9999) gives 1999, it should be 1 day + or -, like you said.

Comment: All of the NSLogged NSDate values above are one day earlier than the corresponding string values.  There is nothing inconsistent.  In terms of the year, obviously the date formatter cannot handle "9999" (or perhaps NSLog `description` cannot print it), but that's an artificial problem.

Comment: @HotLicks I used "print description" to see the values. That contain 9999, but when I do "print description" for second date it shows 1999. It's not just the NSLog.

Comment: Keep in mind that the internal representation of a NSDate is something like an 8-byte value in milliseconds before/after Jan 1, 2001.  The maximum date that can be represented is finite and works out to be about the year 6459, if I did my math right.  The code is doing its best to make sense of an obviously bogus date.

Comment: (Try getting `[NSDate distantFuture]` and see what it displays as.)

Comment: (Probably the date formatter should have done what it usually does for bogus character dates and returned nil.  That's the closest thing I can see to an error here.)

Answer (score -3):

Try This Code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:@"8/20/2013"];
NSTimeZone *currentTimeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"];
NSInteger currentGMTOffset = [currentTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSInteger gmtOffset = [utcTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:date];
NSTimeInterval gmtInterval = currentGMTOffset - gmtOffset;
NSDate *destinationDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:gmtInterval sinceDate:date];
NSLog(@"DateString : %@", destinationDate);
```

You will get exact output which you want.

Comment: Kind of silly (and error-prone) to use NSDateFormatter and then manually do timezone arithmetic, vs simply setting the formatter for the desired timezone.